# Python switch variables each 2nd loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
proxies1 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}
proxies2 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}
proxies3 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}
proxies4 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}
proxies5 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}
proxies6 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}
proxies7 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}
proxies8 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}
proxies9 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}
proxies10 = {'http': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128', 'https': 'http://199.193.251.1:3128'}


ProxyList = [proxies1,proxies2,proxies3,proxies4,proxies5,proxies6,proxies7,proxies8,proxies9,proxies10]
```

I'm trying to switch proxies every time this loop loops 2 times...

```
for channel in ChannelList:
    ChannelURL = ("https://url.com/b/" + str(channel) + "/app/basic/a/plusone/buzz:" + videoID + "?cbp=ck8a3bhdyjck&sview=1&cid=5&soc-app=115&soc-platform=1&spath=/b/" + str(channel) +"/app/basic/stream/" + videoID)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(ChannelURL, PROXY VARIABLE GOES HERE).text, "html.parser")
    for inp in soup.select(".jlvUSc input[name]"):
        if inp["name"] not in form_data1:
            form_data1[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
    s.post(ChannelURL, form_data1)
```

Python 3.4

I'm working with [Python Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will switch proxies every two loops:

```
for loop,channel in enumerate(ChannelList):
    proxies = ProxyList[loop // 2 % len(ProxyList)]
```

Comment: just to be sire I'm replacing `for channel in ChannelList:` with `for loop,channel in enumerate(ChannelList):` ?

Comment: Typo ^ I meant sure

Answer (score 0):

So what you need, is every loop, invert a flag. When your flag is true get the next proxy from the list

```
proxyflag = False
Indexer =0
for channel in ChannelList:
if (proxyflag):
  Indexer+=1
ProxyIndex = Indexer%len(ProxyList)
Proxy = ProxyList[ProxyIndex]
ChannelURL = ("https://url.com/b/" + str(channel) + "/app/basic/a/plusone/buzz:" + videoID + "?cbp=ck8a3bhdyjck&sview=1&cid=5&soc-app=115&soc-platform=1&spath=/b/" + str(channel) +"/app/basic/stream/" + videoID)
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(ChannelURL, Proxy).text, "html.parser")
for inp in soup.select(".jlvUSc input[name]"):
    if inp["name"] not in form_data1:
        form_data1[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
s.post(ChannelURL, form_data1)
proxyflag = not(proxyflag)
```